# How to create 301 redirect rule in functions.php

Tags: php, wordpress, url, redirect

first of all, sorry if my english it's not perfect...

For various reasons (VM in inconsistent state and mainly outdated format), I am migrating a website to Wordpress.

The web had a news channel that no longer works, but these were still in the old database. I wrote a small script with Python to generate an XML with the import format used by wordpress, from a CSV with the news taken from the database.

The news had an associated ID, from which I generated the post ID and the url with the format "mywebsite.com/on-1234" ('on' comes from "Old News"). On the old site the news had the format "mywebsite.com/news.html?id=1234". These old links and are currently linked from a large number of sites (We are a center for environmental research).

I know how to redirect from one link to another, but it can be a tedious task to do it in each news individually as there are hundreds ... Is there some way to detect the pattern "/news.html?id=1234" and replace it with " on-1234" (keeping the number) so it redirects to that route?.

I have searched for information about it and no solution covers my need.

Thanks in advance

Comment: How are you doing the redirection right now?

Comment: I could do it with "get_the_permalink" or with a redirect plugin but in both cases, I could only do it individually. Anyway, the @ninnypants solution has worked perfectly. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most efficient way to do something like this outside the webserver is to hook into WordPress' `parse_request` hook and handle the redirect there. Here's some sample code that hooks into `parse_request` checks to see if the request was to the old `news.html` if it was and has an id it will direct to a post with the id `mywebsite.com/?p=1234` if that doesn't match the post id you could tweak slightly for the same affect.

```php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Old News Redirect
 * Plugin URI:
 * Description: Redirect old news urls.
 * Version: 0.0.1
 * Author: ninnypants
 * Author URI:
 * License: GPL2
 */

namespace StackOverflow\OldNews;

function maybe_redirect( $wp ) {
    if ( 'news.html' === $wp->request ) {
        $id = filter_input( INPUT_GET, 'id', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT );
        if ( empty( $id ) ) {
            return;
        }

        wp_safe_redirect( add_query_arg( 'p', $id, home_url() ) );
        exit;
    }
}
add_action( 'parse_request', __NAMESPACE__ . '\maybe_redirect' );
```

I tested this code by dropping it in the `mu-plugins`directory of one of my tests sites, and that's the approach I would suggest if you don't want any users to be able to shut it off or it to break if someone changes the theme.

Comment: It works perfectly! Thank you very much! i did a litte modification because i added "100" to the post ID value in the importation to avoid conflicts with existent posts so I changed the $id value with "$id = '100'. $id;" and works perfect. Thanks!!!